# TypeError: e.fixers is undefined error for prefixfree on dynamically loaded iframes

Tags: javascript, html, vendor-prefix, prefixfree

I'm dynamically loading an iframe with some code to execute within - it's a code playground with codemirror instance under it. One of the pieces of code that executes inside of iframe is the [prefixfree.min.js from Lea Verou](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

On load / unload of the iframe I get the following error:

```
TypeError: i is null


...;u(s)&&t.indexOf(s)===-1&&t.push(s)}}},u=function(e){return StyleFix.camelCase(e...


prefixfree.min.js (line 5, col 3756)
TypeError: e.fixers is undefined


...,0,t)},fix:function(t,n,r){for(var i=0;i<e.fixers.length;i++)t=e.fixers[i](t,n,r...
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: You could start by using the non-minified version of prefixfree. That way you'll get more intelligible error messages; the code will likely have comments; the variables will have more helpful names; and with proper line numbering you'll be able to set breakpoints. (Of course, change back to minified once you get it running live - the script will load faster.)

Comment: Unfortunately cdnjs doesn't provide the un-minified version of prefixfree [1] and this error doesn't come when I use the prefixer off my server or in my local. [1] https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prefixfree

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the un-minified version, then you can get an error report that tells if variable `self.fixer` is not defined.

So it will need to check if that variable is defined before executing any codes after it.

I have pulled a request [here](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/pull/6100)

If you are not required to use `cdnjs`, then you can download [this un-minified prefixfree](https://github.com/webdev20/prefixfree/blob/c2bf9ea9210e580a069f6f607e5b90290a2c9795/prefixfree.js) and then load it into your application or minify it first.

Comment: Wasn't the previous unedited answer better detailed?

Comment: Will give it a try in sometime.